# Has the US Department of Justice ever been so quick to disagree with SCOTUS?

Tags: united-states, history, supreme-court, justice-department

Within a very short time after the US SCOTUS struck down the New York gun laws, the US Department of justice has [come out against the decision.](https://www.businessinsider.com/justice-department-opposes-supreme-court-gun-ruling-2022-6)

Has the Department of Justice ever been this quick to oppose a SCOTUS decision?

Comment: They probably had some preparation time, knowing about when the decision would be announced.

Comment: @Trilarion: there's in fact a CNN piece that the Biden administration had expected this decision and had been preparing for months. It's worth recalling that the decision was also leaked before it was officially published, which in itself was a bit of a first, or at least uncommon occurrence.

Comment: @Fizz This question is about the gun decision, but you seem to be thinking about the abortion one?  Or were both leaked?

Comment: @zibadawatimmy indeed. But that also answers the question, albeit with a "precedent" that was only a about a day later :-)

Comment: The Supreme Court directly rules against the Department of Justice reasonably often. How fast do you consider that "DOJ disagreeing with SCOTUS?"